# (sequence or prioritize) Math over French

Tags: word-choice

I have made up the two similar sentences below.

> (1) Mr. Brown is teaching two subjects this term. In his lesson plans,
> he always **sequences** Math over French because he likes Math more.

and

> (2) Mr. Brown is teaching two subjects this term. In his lesson plans,
> he always **prioritizes** Math over French because he likes Math more.

What I am trying to say is that he always prepares his Math lessons first because he likes the subject.

Which word is correct: sequence or prioritize?

Comment: Asking if something is correct is off-topic here, so I've voted to close this question as it is written. What did your research tell you? What is the reason for your confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "prioritize" is to decide what is more important. It does not necessarily indicate what you do first. Someone might well say, "I prioritize math over French, so I always do the French first to get it over with so I can then get on to the more important math."

To "sequence" is to put things in a desired order. But we don't normally say "sequence A over B". You might say "sequence A before B", that would make more sense, but it's not a common thing to say.

If I wanted to express the idea you're describing, I'd say it the way you did when explaining your examples rather than in either of your examples. That is, I'd say, "He prepares his math lessons first because he likes that subject."